# Java - Collection base

Tags: c#, java, collections

What is the equivalent of C# CollectionBase in Java?

Answer (score 6):

[`AbstractCollection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) is probably the closest; but since `CollectionBase` implements `IList`, you might want [`AbstractList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) instead.

Answer (score -1):

[collection interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)